# Euler angle in ellipsoid rotation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, rotations, mathematical-modeling, fluid-dynamics

I am modeling an ellipsoid tumbling in a flow field. I have derived an expression for the Euler angle $\phi(t)$ of the rotation in the $x$-$y$ plane as a function of time, but its range is only $\pi$, from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. The range should be $2\pi$, and I would like to know if it is possible in this case to identify the angle $-\pi/2$ with $\pi/2$ since the ellipsoid is symmetric, and thus allow this function to represent a full rotation through $2\pi$ of the ellipsoid (over two periods of $\phi$).

Here is what I have found for $\phi$.
$$
\phi(t) = \arctan\left( \sqrt{\frac{1+r}{1-r}}\tan \left(\frac{\gamma}{2} \sqrt{1-r^2} t\right)\right),
$$

where $r = \frac{{a_1}^2 - {a_2}^2}{{a_1}^2 + {a_2}^2}$, $a_1, a_2$ being the semi-principal axes, and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ is a predetermined constant.

It looks like this:

[image]

I believe this is all the information required to answer my question; however, below I have included a derivation of this equation in case this is useful.

**Derivation**

This derivation follows [this](http://pre.aps.org/abstract/PRE/v83/i4/e041911) publication exactly (I hope!), the results of which I am attempting to reproduce. Represent a linear shear flow field in the laboratory frame as
$$
\mathbf{G'} = \left( \begin{matrix} 0&\gamma&0\\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
where $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$, then rotate $\mathbf{G'}$ into the reference frame of the ellipsoid by $\mathbf{G} = \mathbf{RG'R}^T$ where
$$
\mathbf{R} = \left( \begin{matrix} \cos \phi& \sin \phi&0\\ -\sin \phi&\cos \phi&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
represents a rotation about the $z$ axis (i.e., in the $x$-$y$ plane). Define $\mathbf{E} = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{G} + \mathbf{G}^T)$ and $\Omega = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{G} - \mathbf{G}^T)$ and then solve the differential equation
$$
\phi' = \Omega_{12} + r\,E_{12}
$$
with $r$ defined as above. I used a computer to obtain an analytic solution to this ODE.

**Possible Issue**

The ODE solver (in *Mathematica*) complained that inverse functions were being used and that thus some solutions may not be found. It is thus possible that I do not have the right solution to the ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\mathbf{G^\prime}$ assumes *only* rotation about the $z$-axis, your ODE reduces to $$\phi^\prime=\frac{\gamma}{2}\left(1 + r\cos{2\phi}\right)$$ You see that this governing equation only requires information from $\phi$ in the range of $[0,\pi)$ (or $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$), because $2\phi$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ (or $(-\pi,\pi]$). This is why it admits an $\operatorname{arctan}$ solution.  If you were to introduce a small perturbation of the Euler angle $\theta$, the above equation would become more complicated and a solution would require a more detailed, less symmetric solution.  So, your interpretation is correct: two of these periods corresponds to one period of rotation for the whole ellipsoid.